# Jquery on function not working in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

im having trouble triggering an event in jquery. Thing is i have set an on change event on a bootstrap modal input field. The event triggers when i close my modal, i want it to trigger even when modal is open. Please help. Thanks

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>
        <span><strong> Current Password:</strong></span>                                                    
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="curr-pass" placeholder="Enter Current Password" name="pass" required />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change","#curr-pass",function(){
        var password = $(this).val();
        console.log(password);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try changing it to the `input` event, as in `on('input', '#curr-pass', ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onBlur or KeyUp event rather than "Change"..

Comment: on keyUp works. im such a dork, i've used this many times but it slipped my mind.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `blur()`event

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("blur","#curr-pass",function(){
        var password = $(this).val();
        console.log(password);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>
        <span><strong> Current Password:</strong></span>                                                    
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="curr-pass" placeholder="Enter Current Password" name="pass" required />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```